# Android ZXing QR code reader library - disable history menu

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am using ZXing's qr code library in my Android app. When I click on scan intent it opens the the CAMERA with QR Code reader, and there is a menu, called 'history'.

How could I disable it or make it do not store the scanned codes?

Please suggest

Comment: You can also use the following library : https://github.com/nipun-birla/QRReaderView

It involves some modifications over the ZXing library and can be used like a custom view unlike ZXing

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/history/HistoryManager.java

I dont know whether it will work or no. But try changing the boolean in
enableHistory = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_ENABLE_HISTORY, true);

to false.

Or you will atleast it will help you to bring closer to your answer.